# I need only the result of selected choice but it displays all other results with any choice

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, while-loop

```
#purpose - program to perform some list operations
list1 = []
list2 = []
print("Select operation.")
print("1.Check Length of two list's are Equal")
print("2.Check sum of two list's are Equal")
print("3.whether any value occur in both ")
print("4.Display Lists")

while True:
    choice = input("Enter any choice ")
    if choice in ('1', '2', '3', '4'):
        list1Len = int(input("Enter the number of elements in list 1 : "))
        for i in range(0, list1Len):
            print("Enter the element ", i+1, ":")
            item1 = int(input())
            list1.append(item1)
        list2Len = int(input("Enter the number of elements in list 2 : "))
        for j in range(0, list2Len):
            print("Enter the element ", j+1, ":")
            item2 = int(input())
            list2.append(item2)
        if choice == '1' and len(list1) == len (list2):
         print(" Length are Equal")
        else :
         print(" Length are Not Equal")
        
        if choice == '2'and sum(list1) == sum (list2):
         print(" Sums are Equal")
        else :
         print("  Sums are Not Equal")
      
        if choice == '3':
         list3 =[x for x in list1 if x in list2][enter image description here][1]
         print("Common elements in both list are \n", list3) 
      
        if choice == '4':
         print( "List 1 is :\n",list1 ,"List 2 is :\n", list2)
```

I need only the result of selected choice but it displays all other results with any choice
it displays all the operations that I included in the code , how to fix it , I provided an image with it .

hope I made it clear enough....

Comment: There are no code to differentiate the choices, only to check whether the input is one of the choices. Incomplete (?)

Comment: how to differentiate the choices ?

Comment: Your If statements are not nested together. Make it into one nested If.
Example
`If choice == 1 and something is True:
 do something
elif choice 1 and something is False:
 do something
elif choice 2....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code did exactly what  you told it to do: check each of the four choices.  You print the failure message even if it's not the right choice.  You need to nest the logic in two levels: one to determine the correct choice, the other to determine the proper response.

```
if choice == '1':
    if len(list1) == len (list2):
        print(" Length are Equal")
    else:
        print(" Length are Not Equal")

elif choice == '2':
    if sum(list1) == sum (list2):
        print(" Sums are Equal")
    else:
        print("  Sums are Not Equal")
```

... and so on

Answer (score 0):

Don't combine testing the choice with testing the result of the corresponding condition. Use nested `if` instead.

```
if choice == '1':
    if len(list1) == len(list2):
        print("Length are Equal")
    else:
        print("Length are Not Equal")
```

The way you wrote it, the `else:` block is executed if they made a different choice or the condition for that choice isn't true.